# CLI reading logger in Python

Tags: python, beginner, console

EDIT
Updated code

This is my first real project in Python, and also my first time using sql databases. The purpose was initially to provide a very simple interface to track my reading hours using logs, but became a bit more complex as I expanded on the idea.

The app consists of 4 primary classes Printer, Logger (main), DB, and Parser. The Parser class parses command line arguments using 'argparse', the DB class handles all interaction with the '.logger.db' file using 'sqlalchemy', the Printer class handles all formatting and output to the terminal, and the Logger is the main class that uses all other classes to provide an interface to the user to perform basic CRUD operations of log or book information on the db.

The class that actually does the most 'work' is the Printer class. All outputted text adheres to a layout, this layout is based on the width of columns as defined in `settings.py`. The main functions of the Printer class are `_fmt_line()` and `print_line()` that are responsible for taking in a line's structure, and transforming it into a formatted string. Example of line structure: `[('hello', 1), ('world', 2)]`, the formatted would interpret this as `print 'hello' to span 1 column and 'world' to span the next 2 columns`. The width of the columns are responsive to the width of the terminal, and completely configurable by the user, like everything else in `settings.py`. Customizability and a clean interface are a priority for me with this program.

Since this is my first project in Python, this script pretty much sums up all of my programming knowledge, and so I'd appreciate any feedback, even down to the spacing between my statements and functions.

### logger.py

```
import os
import logging
import sys
import textwrap
import random

import settings

from itertools import zip_longest
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from contextlib import contextmanager
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select, insert, update, and_, or_, Column, ForeignKey, CheckConstraint, Integer, String, Date, Time
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref, declarative_base, Session


logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s', level=logging.INFO)


Base = declarative_base()


class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = "book"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String)
    author = Column(String)

    logs = relationship("Log", backref=backref("book"))


class Log(Base):
    __tablename__ = "log"
    __table_args__ = (
            CheckConstraint("time_start < time_end"),
            CheckConstraint("page_start < page_end"),
            )

    book_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("book.id"), nullable=False)

    date = Column(Date, primary_key=True)
    time_start = Column(Time, primary_key=True)
    time_end = Column(Time, nullable=False)
    page_start = Column(Integer)
    page_end = Column(Integer)
    depth = Column(Integer)
    comments = Column(String)


engine = create_engine("sqlite:///.logger.db?foreign_keys=1")


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


session = Session(engine)


@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()


def delta_from_time(start_time, end_time):
    start_time_delta = timedelta(hours=start_time.hour, minutes=start_time.minute)
    end_time_delta = timedelta(hours=end_time.hour, minutes=end_time.minute)
    return (end_time_delta - start_time_delta).seconds


def get_book(book_id):
    db = DB()
    try:
        book_id = int(book_id)
        if db._is_valid_book_id(book_id):
            return db.book_obj(book_id)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return


def get_item(item_id):
    db = DB()
    book = get_book(item_id)

    if book:
        return book

    try:
        id = datetime.strptime(item_id, '%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M')
        date = id.date()
        time_start = id.time()
        if db._is_valid_log_id(date, time_start):
            return db.log_obj(date, time_start)
    except ValueError:
        pass

    return


def is_valid_book_title(title):
    if len(title) > settings.LIMIT_BOOK_TITLE_LENGTH:
        return False

    return title 


def is_valid_author_name(name):
    if len(name) > settings.LIMIT_AUTHOR_NAME_LENGTH:
        return False

    return name


def is_valid_date(date):
    try:
        date = datetime.strptime(date, settings.INPUT_DATE_FORMAT)
        return date.date()
    except ValueError:
        return False


def is_valid_time_span(time_span):
    try:
        start, end = [datetime.strptime(t, '%H:%M').time() for t in time_span.split('-')]
        if start > end:
            return False
        return start, end
    except ValueError:
        return False


def is_valid_page_span(page_span):
    try:
        start, end = map(int, page_span.split('-'))
        if start > end:
            return False
        return start, end
    except ValueError:
        return False


def is_valid_comments(comments):
    if len(comments) > settings.LIMIT_COMMENTS_LENGTH:
        return False

    return comments


def is_valid_depth(depth):
    try:
        depth = int(depth)
        return depth
    except ValueError:
        return False


class Add:
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = DB()
        self.printer = Printer()

        self.fields_add_book = {
            'title': {
                'required': False,
                'check': is_valid_book_title
            },
            'author': {
                'required': False,
                'check': is_valid_author_name
            }
        }
        self.fields_add_log = {
            'date': {
                'required': True,
                'check': is_valid_date
            },
            'time': {
                'required': True,
                'check': is_valid_time_span
            },
            'pages': {
                'required': False,
                'check': is_valid_page_span,
            },
            'depth': {
                'required': False,
                'check': is_valid_depth,
            },
            'comments': {
                'required': False,
                'check': is_valid_comments
            }
        }

    def run(self, args):
        if args == []:
            response = self.printer.add_book(self.fields_add_book)
            self.db.insert_book(response)
            self.printer.print_action_add()

            return True

        book = get_book(args[0])

        if not book:
            self.printer.print_err_invalid_book_id()

        elif len(args) == 1:
            response  = self.printer.add_log(self.fields_add_log, book)
            response = {
                'book_id': book.id, 
                'date': response['date'], 
                'time_start': response['time'][0] , 
                'time_end': response['time'][1], 
                'page_start': response['pages'][0] if response['pages'] else None, 
                'page_end': response['pages'][0] if response['pages'] else None,
                'depth': response['depth'], 
                'comments': response['comments']
            }

            log_id = (response['date'], response['time_start'])

            if self.db._is_valid_log_id(*log_id):
                self.printer.print_err_log_exists(*log_id)

            self.db.insert_log(response)
            self.printer.print_action_add()

            return True

        return False


class Edit:
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = DB()
        self.printer = Printer()

        self.fields_edit_book = {
            'title': {
                'required': False,
                'check': is_valid_book_title
            },
            'author': {
                'required': False,
                'check': is_valid_author_name
            }
        }
        self.fields_edit_log = {
            'date': {
                'required': True,
                'check': is_valid_date
            },
            'time': {
                'required': True,
                'check': is_valid_time_span
            },
            'pages': {
                'required': False,
                'check': is_valid_page_span,
            },
            'depth': {
                'required': False,
                'check': is_valid_depth,
            },
            'comments': {
                'required': False,
                'check': is_valid_comments
            }
        }

    def run(self, args):
        if len(args) != 1:
            return False

        item = get_item(args[0])

        if not item:
            self.printer.print_err_invalid_item_id()

        if isinstance(item, Log):
            response = self.printer.edit_log(self.fields_edit_log, item.book)
            response = {
                'date': response['date'], 
                'time_start': response['time'][0] , 
                'time_end': response['time'][1], 
                'page_start': response['pages'][0] if response['pages'] else None, 
                'page_end': response['pages'][0] if response['pages'] else None,
                'depth': response['depth'], 
                'comments': response['comments']
            }

            self.db.update_log(item.date, item.time_start, response)
            self.printer.print_action_edit()
            pass

        elif isinstance(item, Book):
            response = self.printer.edit_book(self.fields_edit_book, item)
            self.db.update_book(item.id, response)
            self.printer.print_action_edit()

        return True


class Remove:
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = DB()
        self.printer = Printer()

    def run(self, args):
        if len(args) < 1:
            return False
        
        books, logs = set(), set()

        for arg in args:
            item = get_item(arg)

            if not item:
                self.printer.print_err_invalid_item_id()
            
            if isinstance(item, Log):
                logs.add(item)

            elif isinstance(item, Book):
                books.add(item)
                for log in item.logs:
                    logs.add(log)

        confirm = self.printer.confirm_delete(books, logs)

        if confirm:
            self.db.delete_items(logs | books)

        self.printer.print_action_delete(confirm)

        return True


class Show:
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = DB()
        self.printer = Printer()

    def run(self, args):
        if args == []:
            books = self.db.get_all_books()
            self.printer.print_all_books(books)

            return True

        item = get_item(args[0])

        if not item:
            self.printer.print_err_invalid_item_id()
        
        if len(args) == 1 and item:
            if isinstance(item, Log):
                book = self.db.book_obj(item.book_id)
                self.printer.print_log_info(book, item)

            elif isinstance(item, Book):
                self.printer.print_book_info(item)

            return True

        return False


class Search:
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = DB()
        self.printer = Printer()


    def run(self, args):
        if len(args) == 1:
            results = self.db.search(args[0])

            self.printer.print_search_results(args[0], results)

            return True
            
        return False


class DB:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def _generate_book_id(self):
        while True:
            book_id = random.randint(1000,9999)
            if not self._is_valid_book_id(book_id):
                return book_id

    def _is_valid_book_id(self, book_id):
        return bool(self.book_obj(book_id))

    def _is_valid_log_id(self, date, time_start):
        return bool(self.log_obj(date, time_start))

    def _log_id(self, date, time_start):
        return and_(Log.date == date, Log.time_start == time_start)

    def search(self, query):
        query = select(Book).where(or_(Book.title.contains(query), Book.author.contains(query)))
        return session.scalars(query).all()

    def book_obj(self, book_id):
        query = select(Book).where(Book.id == book_id)
        return session.scalar(query)

    def log_obj(self, date, time_start):
        query = select(Log).where(self._log_id(date, time_start))
        return session.scalar(query)
    
    def get_all_books(self):
        query = select(Book).order_by(Book.title)
        return session.scalars(query).all()

    def update_book(self, book_id, info):
        with session_scope() as session:
            query = update(Book).where(Book.id == book_id).values(**info)
            session.execute(query)

    def update_log(self, date, time_start, info):
        with session_scope() as session:
            query = update(Log).where(self._log_id(date, time_start)).values(**info)
            session.execute(query)

    def insert_log(self, info):
        with session_scope() as session:
            query = insert(Log).values(**info)
            session.execute(query)

    def insert_book(self, info):
        with session_scope() as session:
            query = insert(Book).values(id=self._generate_book_id(), **info)
            session.execute(query)

    def delete_items(self, items):
        with session_scope() as session:
            for item in items:
                session.delete(item)


class Printer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.width = self._find_apt_value(settings.WIDTH, os.get_terminal_size().columns)
        self.columns = self._find_apt_value(settings.COLUMNS.copy(), self.width)

        self.margin = settings.MARGIN
        self.gutter = settings.GUTTER

        self.span_indent = settings.SPAN_INDENT
        self.span_footnote = settings.SPAN_FOOTNOTE

        self.span_field_name = settings.SPAN_FIELD_NAME
        self.span_field_value = settings.SPAN_FIELD_VALUE

        self.align_field_name = settings.ALIGN_FIELD_NAME
        self.align_field_value = settings.ALIGN_FIELD_VALUE
        self.align_footnote = settings.ALIGN_FOOTNOTE

        self._margin = ' ' * self.margin
        self._gutter = ' ' * self.gutter
        self._indent = ('', self.span_indent, 'l')

        self.format_date = settings.FORMAT_DATE

        self.enable_color = settings.ENABLE_COLOR

        self.color_row_background = settings.COLOR_ROW_BACKGROUND
        self.color_foreground = settings.COLOR_FOREGROUND
        self.color_normal = settings.COLOR_NORMAL
        
        self.headers_table_book = settings.HEADERS_TABLE_BOOK
        self.headers_table_log = settings.HEADERS_TABLE_LOG

        self.str_log_singular = settings.STR_LOG_SINGULAR
        self.str_log_plural = settings.STR_LOG_PLURAL

        self.str_book_singular = settings.STR_BOOK_SINGULAR
        self.str_book_plural = settings.STR_BOOK_PLURAL

        self.str_hour_singular = settings.STR_HOUR_SINGULAR
        self.str_hour_plural = settings.STR_HOUR_PLURAL

        self.str_page_singular = settings.STR_PAGE_SINGULAR
        self.str_page_plural = settings.STR_PAGE_PLURAL

        self.str_minute_singular = settings.STR_MINUTE_SINGULAR
        self.str_minute_plural = settings.STR_MINUTE_PLURAL

        self.str_has_comments = settings.STR_HAS_COMMENTS

        self.str_no_pages = settings.STR_NO_PAGES
        self.str_no_author = settings.STR_NO_AUTHOR
        self.str_no_title = settings.STR_NO_TITLE
        self.str_no_logs = settings.STR_NO_LOGS
        self.str_no_depth = settings.STR_NO_DEPTH
        self.str_no_comments = settings.STR_NO_COMMENTS

        self.str_no_author_expand = settings.STR_NO_AUTHOR_EXPAND
        self.str_no_title_expand = settings.STR_NO_TITLE_EXPAND
        self.str_no_comments_expand = settings.STR_NO_COMMENTS_EXPAND

        self.action_delete = settings.ACTION_DELETE
        self.action_add = settings.ACTION_ADD
        self.action_edit = settings.ACTION_EDIT

        self.rows_book_expand = settings.ROWS_BOOK_EXPAND

        self.fields_log_info = settings.FIELDS_LOG_INFO
        self.fields_add_edit_book = settings.FIELDS_ADD_EDIT_BOOK
        self.fields_add_edit_log = settings.FIELDS_ADD_EDIT_LOG
        self.fields_usage = settings.FIELDS_USAGE

        self.header_usage = settings.HEADER_USAGE
        self.header_add_book = settings.HEADER_ADD_BOOK
        self.header_add_log = settings.HEADER_ADD_LOG
        self.header_edit_book = settings.HEADER_EDIT_BOOK
        self.header_edit_log = settings.HEADER_EDIT_LOG
        self.header_search = settings.HEADER_SEARCH
        self.header_remove = settings.HEADER_REMOVE
        self.header_show_all_books = settings.HEADER_SHOW_ALL_BOOKS
        self.header_show_book = settings.HEADER_SHOW_BOOK
        self.header_show_log = settings.HEADER_SHOW_LOG
        self.header_err_invalid_item_id = settings.HEADER_ERR_INVALID_ITEM_ID
        self.header_err_invalid_book_id = settings.HEADER_ERR_INVALID_BOOK_ID

        self.err_invalid_item_id = settings.ERR_INVALID_ITEM_ID
        self.err_invalid_book_id = settings.ERR_INVALID_BOOK_ID
        self.err_required_field = settings.ERR_REQUIRED_FIELD
        self.err_log_exists = settings.ERR_LOG_EXISTS

        self.msg_no_books = settings.MSG_NO_BOOKS
        self.msg_no_results = settings.MSG_NO_RESULTS
        self.msg_no_logs = settings.MSG_NO_LOGS

        self.limit_prompt_delete_book_title_length = settings.LIMIT_PROMPT_DELETE_BOOK_TITLE_LENGTH
        self.limit_query_print_length = settings.LIMIT_QUERY_PRINT_LENGTH

        self.prompt_delete = settings.PROMPT_DELETE

        self.responses_confirm = settings.RESPONSES_CONFIRM
      
    def _parse_layout_options(self, options, locals=None):
        layout = []

        if not options:
            return [('', 0, 'l')]

        for param, option in options.items():
            if param == 'BLANK':
                layout.append(('', option['span'], 'l'))
            else:
                if not option['show']:
                    continue
                name = locals[param] if locals else option['name']
                layout.append((name, option['span'], option['align']))

        return layout
  
    def _find_apt_value(self, items, value):
        apt_value = items.get('default')
        for item in items:
            if item != 'default' and value >= item:
                apt_value = items[item]
        return apt_value

    def _truncate(self, string, width, align=None):
        if len(string) > width:
            string = f'{string[:width-3].strip()}...'
            if align and align == 'l':
                return string.ljust(width)
            if align and align == 'r':
                return string.rjust(width)
        return string

    def _format_item(self, string, width, align, wrap):
        items = []

        if not string:
            return [(''.ljust(width), width, align)]

        if isinstance(string, dict):
            string = self._find_apt_value(string, width)

        string = str(string)
        strings = textwrap.wrap(string, width=width) if wrap else [self._truncate(string, width, align)]

        for string in strings:
            if align == 'l':
                items.append((string.ljust(width), width, align))
            if align == 'r':
                items.append((string.rjust(width), width, align))

        return items

    def _format_line(self, items, wrap=False, full_just=False, background_color=''):
        current_index = 0

        formatted_items = []

        for string, span, align in items:
            if span <= 0:
                continue

            width = (span - 1) * self.gutter + sum(self.columns[current_index:current_index+span])
            current_index += span

            if isinstance(string, list):
                ins_str = []
                for item in string:
                    ins_str.extend(self._format_item(item, width, align, wrap))
                formatted_items.append(ins_str)
            else:
                formatted_items.append(self._format_item(string, width, align, wrap)) 
            
        lines = [list(field) for field in list(zip_longest(*formatted_items, fillvalue=None))]

        line_strings = []

        for line in lines:
            line_fields = []
            for j, sub_f in enumerate(line):
                if not sub_f:
                    width = lines[0][j][1]
                    line_fields.append(''.ljust(width))
                else:
                    line_fields.append(sub_f[0])
            line_strings.append(line_fields)

        for i, line_string in enumerate(line_strings):
            line_string = self._margin + self._gutter.join(line_string)

            if full_just:
                line_string = line_string.ljust(self.width)

            if self.enable_color:
                line_string = f'{self.color_foreground}{background_color}{line_string}{self.color_normal}'

            line_strings[i] = line_string
        
        return line_strings
    
    def _format_count(self, count, plural_name, singular_name):
        name = singular_name if count == 1 else plural_name
        return f'{count} {name}'

    def _format_count_log(self, log_count):
        return self._format_count(log_count, self.str_log_plural, self.str_log_singular)

    def _format_count_book(self, book_count):
        return self._format_count(book_count, self.str_book_plural, self.str_book_singular)

    def _format_count_page(self, page_count):
        return self._format_count(page_count, self.str_page_plural, self.str_page_singular)

    def _format_count_hour(self, hour_count):
        return self._format_count(hour_count, self.str_hour_plural, self.str_hour_singular)

    def _format_count_minute(self, minute_count):
        return self._format_count(minute_count, self.str_minute_plural, self.str_minute_singular)

    def _format_time(self, hours, minutes):
        hours_fmt = self._format_count_hour(hours)
        minutes_fmt = self._format_count_minute(minutes)
        if hours == 0:
            return minutes_fmt
        elif minutes == 0:
            return hours_fmt
        return f'{hours_fmt}, {minutes_fmt}'

    def print_line(self, items, wrap=False, new_line_before=False, new_line_after=False, full_just=False, background_color='', print_method=logging.info):
        line_strings = self._format_line(items, wrap, full_just, background_color)

        if new_line_before:
            print_method('')

        for line_string in line_strings:
            print_method(line_string)

        if new_line_after:
            print_method('')

    def print_empty_line(self):
        self.print_line([('', 1, 'l')])

    def print_item_count(self, book_count=None, log_count=None):
        string = ''

        log_count_string = self._format_count_log(log_count)
        book_count_string = self._format_count_book(book_count)

        if book_count is not None and log_count is not None:
            string = f'{book_count_string}, {log_count_string}'

        elif book_count is not None:
            string = book_count_string

        elif log_count is not None:
            string = log_count_string

        items = [self._indent, (string, self.span_footnote, 'l')]
        self.print_line(items, new_line_before=True)

    def print_header(self, header):
        items = [self._indent, (header, 6-self.span_indent, 'l')]
        self.print_line(items, new_line_after=True)

    def print_field(self, name, value):
        items = [self._indent, (name, self.span_field_name, self.align_field_name), (value, self.span_field_value, self.align_field_value)] 
        self.print_line(items, wrap=True)

    def print_action(self, action, **kwargs):
        items = [self._indent, (action, self.span_footnote, self.align_footnote)]
        self.print_line(items, **kwargs)

    def print_error(self, error, header=None, exit=False, **kwargs):
        if header:
            self.print_header(header)

        items = [self._indent, (error, self.span_footnote, self.align_footnote)]
        self.print_line(items, wrap=True, print_method=logging.error, **kwargs)

        if exit:
            sys.exit(1)

    def print_table_headers(self, headers, **kwargs):
        items = self._parse_layout_options(headers)
        self.print_line(items, **kwargs)

    def print_table_book(self, books, show_count=True):
        headers = self.headers_table_book
        highlight = True
        total_log_count = 0

        self.print_table_headers(headers)

        for book in books:
            id = book.id
            author = self.str_no_author if not book.author else book.author
            log_count = self.str_no_logs if not book.logs else len(book.logs)
            title = self.str_no_title if not book.title else book.title

            total_log_count += len(book.logs)

            items = self._parse_layout_options(headers, locals=locals())

            if self.enable_color and highlight:
                self.print_line(items, background_color=self.color_row_background, full_just=True)
                highlight = False
            else:
                self.print_line(items)
                highlight = True

        if show_count:
            self.print_item_count(len(books), total_log_count)

    def print_table_log(self, logs, show_count=True):
        headers = self.headers_table_log 
        highlight=True

        logs.sort(key=lambda r: r.date, reverse=True)

        self.print_table_headers(headers, new_line_before=True)

        for log in logs:
            book_id = log.book_id
            date = self.format_date.copy()
            time = f'{log.time_start.strftime("%H:%M")} {log.time_end.strftime("%H:%M")}'
            depth = log.depth if log.depth else self.str_no_depth
            comments = self.str_has_comments if log.comments else self.str_no_comments

            if log.page_start and log.page_end:
                pages = f'{str(log.page_start).ljust(4)} {str(log.page_end).ljust(4)}'
            else:
                pages = self.str_no_pages

            for item in date:
                date[item] = log.date.strftime(date[item])

            items = self._parse_layout_options(headers, locals=locals())

            if self.enable_color and highlight:
                self.print_line(items, background_color=self.color_row_background, full_just=True)
                highlight = False
            else:
                self.print_line(items)
                highlight = True

        if show_count:
            self.print_item_count(log_count=len(logs))
    
    def print_books(self, header, books, empty_message):
        self.print_header(header)

        if not books:
            self.print_error(empty_message)
        else:
            self.print_table_book(books)
        
    def print_book_expand(self, book, new_line_before=False, new_line_after=False):
        rows = self.rows_book_expand

        id = book.id
        title = self.str_no_title_expand if not book.title else book.title
        author = self.str_no_author_expand if not book.author else book.author

        if new_line_before:
            self.print_empty_line()

        for row in rows:
            items = self._parse_layout_options(row, locals=locals())
            self.print_line(items, wrap=True)

        if new_line_after:
            self.print_empty_line()

    def print_book_stats(self, book):
        total_page_count, total_hour_count = 0, 0

        for log in book.logs:
            if log.page_end and log.page_start:
                total_page_count += log.page_end - log.page_start
            total_hour_count += delta_from_time(log.time_start, log.time_end) / 3600

        items = [self._indent, (f'{self._format_count_page(total_page_count)}, {self._format_count_hour(round(total_hour_count, 1))}', 6-self.span_indent, 'l')]

        self.print_line(items, new_line_before=True)

    def print_book_info(self, book):
        header = self.header_show_book
        empty_message = self.msg_no_logs
        self.print_header(header)

        self.print_book_expand(book)
        
        if not book.logs:
            self.print_error(empty_message, new_line_before=True)
        else:
            self.print_book_stats(book)
            self.print_table_log(book.logs)
    
    def print_err_invalid_item_id(self):
        header = self.header_err_invalid_item_id
        error = self.err_invalid_item_id
        self.print_error(error, header=header, exit=True)

    def print_err_invalid_book_id(self):
        header = self.header_err_invalid_book_id
        error = self.err_invalid_book_id
        self.print_error(error, header=header, exit=True)

    def print_err_log_exists(self, hour, time_start):
        error = self.err_log_exists.format(hour, time_start)
        self.print_error(error, exit=True, new_line_before=True)

    def print_action_delete(self, response):
        action = self.action_delete[response]
        self.print_action(action, new_line_before=True)

    def print_action_add(self):
        action = self.action_add
        self.print_action(action, new_line_before=True)

    def print_action_edit(self):
        action = self.action_edit
        self.print_action(action, new_line_before=True)

    def print_usage(self):
        self.print_header(self.header_usage)
        for name, value in self.fields_usage.items():
            self.print_field(name,value)

    def print_all_books(self, books):
        header = self.header_show_all_books
        empty_message = self.msg_no_books
        self.print_books(header, books, empty_message)
    
    def print_search_results(self, query, results):
        query = self._truncate(query, self.limit_query_print_length)
        header = self.header_search.format(query)
        empty_message = self.msg_no_results
        self.print_books(header, results, empty_message)
    
    def print_log_info(self, book, log):
        header = self.header_show_log
        fields = self.fields_log_info

        time_read = delta_from_time(log.time_start, log.time_end)
        time_read = self._format_time(time_read // 3600, (time_read // 60)%60)
        pages_read = self.str_no_pages if not log.page_end or not log.page_start else log.page_end - log.page_start
        comments = self.str_no_comments_expand if not log.comments else log.comments

        self.print_header(header)
        self.print_book_expand(book, new_line_after=True)
        
        for var_name, name in fields.items():
            value = locals()[var_name]
            self.print_field(name, value)

        self.print_table_log([log])

    def input(self, name, accepted_responses={}, required=False, check_response=None, error='', bool=False, exit_on_error=False):
        fields = [self._indent, (name, self.span_field_name, self.align_field_name)]
        line = self._format_line(fields)
        response = input(f'{line[0]}{self._gutter}')

        if not response and required:
            error = self.err_required_field.format(name) 

        elif not response and not required:
            return

        elif accepted_responses and response.lower() in accepted_responses:
            if bool:
                return True
            return response

        elif check_response:
            response = check_response(response)
            if response is not False:
                if bool:
                    return True
                return response

        if error:
            self.print_error(error, new_line_before=True)

        if exit_on_error:
            sys.exit(1)

        if bool:
            return False

        return response

    def confirm_delete(self, books, logs):
        header = self.header_remove
        prompt = self.prompt_delete

        if books:
            book_title = self._truncate(next(iter(books)).title, self.limit_prompt_delete_book_title_length)

        log_count = self._format_count_log(len(logs))
        book_count = self._format_count_book(len(books))
        text = ''

        if len(books) == 1 and logs:
            text += f'\"{book_title}\" and {log_count}'
        
        elif len(books) == 1 and not logs:
            text += f'\"{book_title}\"'
        
        elif books and logs:
            text += f'{book_count} and {log_count}'
        
        elif not books:
            text = log_count
        
        elif not logs:
            text = book_count

        prompt['prompt']['name'] = prompt['prompt']['name'].format(text)
        items = self._parse_layout_options(prompt)

        self.print_header(header)
        self.print_line(items, wrap=True)

        input = self.input('', accepted_responses=self.responses_confirm, bool=True)

        return input

    def add_edit_item(self, header, fields, book=None):
        self.print_header(header)

        if book:
            self.print_book_expand(book, new_line_after=True)

        response = {} 

        for field in fields:
            name = fields[field]['name']
            check = fields[field]['check']
            error = fields[field]['error']
            required = fields[field]['required']

            response[field] = self.input(name, check_response=check, error=error, required=required, exit_on_error=True)

        return response

    def add_edit_book(self, header, check_fields, book=None):
        fields = self.fields_add_edit_book.copy()

        for field in fields:
            fields[field].update(check_fields[field])

        response = self.add_edit_item(header, fields, book=book)

        return response
    
    def add_edit_log(self, header, check_fields, book):
        fields = self.fields_add_edit_log.copy()

        for field in fields:
            fields[field].update(check_fields[field])

        response = self.add_edit_item(header, fields, book=book)

        return response

    def add_book(self, check_fields):
        header = self.header_add_book
        response = self.add_edit_book(header, check_fields)

        return response

    def add_log(self, check_fields, book):
        header = self.header_add_log
        response = self.add_edit_log(header, check_fields, book)

        return response

    def edit_book(self, check_fields, book):
        header = self.header_edit_book
        response = self.add_edit_book(header, check_fields, book=book)

        return response

    def edit_log(self, check_fields, book):
        header = self.header_edit_log
        response = self.add_edit_log(header, check_fields, book)

        return response


def main():
    db = DB()
    printer = Printer()
    commands = {
        'add': Add,
        'edit': Edit,
        'remove': Remove,
        'show': Show,
        'search': Search
    }

    if len(sys.argv[1:]) == 0:
        printer.print_usage()
        sys.exit(1)

    args = sys.argv[2:]

    try:
        command = commands[sys.argv[1]]
        command = command()
    except KeyError:
        printer.print_usage()
        sys.exit(1)

    if not command.run(args):
        printer.print_usage()
        sys.exit(1)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### settings.py

````
ENABLE_COLOR = True

GUTTER = 3

MARGIN = 2

COLUMNS = {
    'default': [4, 8, 11, 9, 5, 8],
    68: [4, 11, 11, 9, 5, 8],
    73: [4, 15, 11, 9, 5, 8]
}

WIDTH = {
    'default': 64,
    68: 68,
    73: 73 
}

INPUT_DATE_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d'

STR_LOG_SINGULAR = 'log'
STR_LOG_PLURAL = 'logs'
STR_BOOK_SINGULAR = 'book'
STR_BOOK_PLURAL = 'books'
STR_HOUR_SINGULAR = 'hour'
STR_HOUR_PLURAL = 'hours'
STR_PAGE_SINGULAR = 'page'
STR_PAGE_PLURAL = 'pages'
STR_MINUTE_SINGULAR = 'minute'
STR_MINUTE_PLURAL = 'minutes'

STR_ADD_BOOK_TITLE_FIELD_NAME = 'Title' 
STR_ADD_BOOK_AUTHOR_FIELD_NAME = 'Author' 
STR_ADD_LOG_DATE_FIELD_NAME = 'Date' 
STR_ADD_LOG_TIME_FIELD_NAME = 'Time' 
STR_ADD_LOG_PAGES_FIELD_NAME = 'Pages' 
STR_ADD_LOG_DEPTH_FIELD_NAME = 'Depth' 
STR_ADD_LOG_COMMENTS_FIELD_NAME = 'Comments' 

STR_EDIT_BOOK_TITLE_FIELD_NAME = {
    'default': 'Title',
    9: 'New title'
}
STR_EDIT_BOOK_AUTHOR_FIELD_NAME = {
    'default': 'Author',
    10: 'New author'
}

FORMAT_DATE = {
    'default': '%d/%m/%y',
    11: '%d %b %Y',
    15: '%a %b %d %Y'
}

SPAN_INDENT = 1
SPAN_FIELD_NAME = 1
SPAN_FIELD_VALUE = 4
SPAN_FOOTNOTE = 3

LIMIT_COMMENTS_LENGTH = 10
LIMIT_BOOK_TITLE_LENGTH = 80
LIMIT_AUTHOR_NAME_LENGTH = 30
LIMIT_PROMPT_DELETE_BOOK_TITLE_LENGTH = 50
LIMIT_QUERY_PRINT_LENGTH = 20

ALIGN_FIELD_NAME = 'r'
ALIGN_FIELD_VALUE = 'l'
ALIGN_ERROR = 'l'
ALIGN_ACTION = 'l'
ALIGN_FOOTNOTE = 'l'

RESPONSES_CONFIRM = {'yes', 'y', 'delete'}

STR_NO_TITLE_EXPAND = 'Unknown Book'
STR_NO_AUTHOR_EXPAND = 'Unknown Author'
STR_NO_COMMENTS_EXPAND = ''
STR_NO_PAGES = ''
STR_NO_TITLE = 'Unknown Book'
STR_NO_AUTHOR = ''
STR_NO_LOGS = ''
STR_NO_DEPTH = ''
STR_NO_COMMENTS = ''
STR_HAS_COMMENTS = '*'

ERR_INVALID_SEARCH_QUERY = 'Enter a valid search.'
ERR_INVALID_COMMAND = 'Enter a valid command: \"add\", \"edit (item ID)\", \"remove (item ID)\", \"show\", \"search (query)\".'
ERR_INVALID_BOOK_ID = 'Could not find a book with the provided ID.'
ERR_INVALID_ITEM_ID = 'Could not find a book or log with the provided ID.'

ERR_LOG_EXISTS = 'A log already exists for \'{}\' at \'{}:{}\'.'
ERR_REQUIRED_FIELD = '\"{}\" is a required field.'
ERR_LIMIT = 'Invalid \"{}\", exceeds limit: {}.'
ERR_FORMAT = 'Invalid \"{}\", format: {}.'

HEADER_ERR_INVALID_SEARCH_QUERY = 'Invalid Search'
HEADER_ERR_INVALID_COMMAND = 'Invalid Command'
HEADER_ERR_INVALID_BOOK_ID = 'Invalid Book ID'
HEADER_ERR_INVALID_ITEM_ID = 'Invalid Item ID'

HEADER_USAGE = 'Usage'
HEADER_REMOVE = 'Delete Items'
HEADER_SEARCH = 'Showing results for \"{}\"'
HEADER_ADD_BOOK = 'Add Book'
HEADER_ADD_LOG = 'Add Log'
HEADER_EDIT_BOOK = 'Edit Book'
HEADER_EDIT_LOG = 'Edit Log'
HEADER_SHOW_ALL_BOOKS = 'All'
HEADER_SHOW_BOOK = 'Book Info'
HEADER_SHOW_LOG = 'Log Info'

MSG_NO_BOOKS = 'No books in library'
MSG_NO_LOGS = 'No logs for this book'
MSG_NO_RESULTS = 'No results'

PROMPT_DELETE = {
    'BLANK': {
        'span': SPAN_INDENT
    },
    'prompt': {
        'name': 'Are you sure you want to delete {}?', 
        'span': 6-SPAN_INDENT, 
        'align': 'l',
        'show': True
    }
}

ACTION_ADD = 'Added'
ACTION_EDIT = 'Edited'
ACTION_DELETE = {
    True: 'Deleted', 
    False: 'Canceled'
}

COLOR_NORMAL = '\x1b[0m'
COLOR_ROW_BACKGROUND = '\x1b[48;2;30;30;30m'
COLOR_FOREGROUND = '\x1b[38;2;245;245;245m'

ROWS_BOOK_EXPAND = [
    {
        'id': {
            'name': '',
            'span': SPAN_INDENT, 
            'align': 'l', 
            'show': True
        },
        'title': {
            'name': '',
            'span': 3, 
            'align': 'l', 
            'show': True
        }
    }, 
    {
        'BLANK': {
            'span': SPAN_INDENT
        },
        'author': {
            'name': '',
            'span': 3, 
            'align': 'l', 
            'show': True
        }
    }
]

HEADERS_TABLE_BOOK = {
    'id': {
        'name': '', 
        'span': 1, 
        'align': 'l', 
        'show': True
    }, 
    'title': {
        'name': 'Title', 
        'span': 2, 
        'align': 'l', 
        'show': True
    }, 
    'author': {
        'name': 'Author', 
        'span': 2, 
        'align': 'l', 
        'show': True
    }, 
    'log_count': {
        'name': 'Logs', 
        'span': 1, 
        'align': 'l', 
        'show': True
    }
}

HEADERS_TABLE_LOG = {
    'BLANK': {
        'span': 1
    },
    'book_id': {
        'name': '', 
        'span': 1, 
        'align': 'l', 
        'show': False
    }, 
    'date': {
        'name': 'Date', 
        'span': 1, 
        'align': 'l', 
        'show': True
    }, 
    'time': {
        'name': 'Time', 
        'span': 1, 
        'align': 'l', 
        'show': True
    }, 
    'pages': {
        'name': 'Pages', 
        'span': 1, 
        'align': 'l', 
        'show': True
    }, 
    'depth': {
        'name': 'Depth', 
        'span': 1, 
        'align': 'r', 
        'show': True
    }, 
    'comments': {
        'name': 'Comments', 
        'span': 1, 
        'align': 'l', 
        'show': True
    }
}

FIELDS_LOG_INFO = {
    'time_read': 'Time',
    'pages_read': 'Pages',
    'comments': 'Comments'
}

FIELDS_ADD_EDIT_BOOK = {
    'title': {
        'name': 'Title',
        'error': ERR_LIMIT.format('Title', LIMIT_BOOK_TITLE_LENGTH),
    },
    'author': {
        'name': 'Author',
        'error':  ERR_LIMIT.format('Author', LIMIT_AUTHOR_NAME_LENGTH)
    }
}

FIELDS_ADD_EDIT_LOG = {
    'date': {
        'name': 'Date',
        'error': ERR_FORMAT.format('Date', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
    },
    'time': {
        'name': 'Time',
        'error': ERR_FORMAT.format('Time', 'H:M-H:M'),
    },
    'pages': {
        'name': 'Pages',
        'error': ERR_FORMAT.format('Pages', 'P-P'),
    },
    'depth': {
        'name': 'Depth',
        'error': 'Invalid \"Depth\", must be a numerical value.',
    },
    'comments': {
        'name': 'Comments',
        'error': ERR_LIMIT.format('Comments', LIMIT_COMMENTS_LENGTH)
    }
}

FIELDS_USAGE = {
    'add': ['Add items', 'Insert a book or log into your database. Run \'logger add [Book-ID]\' to add a log, or \'logger add\' to add a book.'],
    'edit': ['Edit items', 'Change the details of a book or log. Run \'logger edit [Book-ID]\' to edit a book or \'logger edit [Log-Date].[Log-Start-Time]\' to edit a log.'],
    'remove': ['Delete items', 'Remove a book or log from your database. Run \'logger remove [Book-ID]\' to delete a book or \'logger remove [Log-Date].[Log-Start-Time]\' to remove a log.'],
    'show': ['Show items', 'Print the details of a book or log.  Run \'logger show\' to show all books in the database, \'logger show [Book-ID]\' to show the details of a book or \'logger show [Log-Date].[Log-Start-Time]\' to show the details of a log.'],
    'search': ['Search books', 'Search for a book by title or author. Run \'logger search [Query]\'']
}
```
````